# Regular Expressions to match exactly

Tags: regex

I currently have this regular expression in my javascript

```
^[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{4}\b]
```

At the moment it will accept any 2 letters in any combination followed by a hyphen and then any 4 digit number again in any combination.

I want to create a regular expression that only accepts either 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'BA', 'BB', or 'BC' in the first section and the 4 digit number to start with either a '1', '2', or '3' and any combination for the following 3 digits all this with keeping the hyphen separating the characters and the digits.

Comment: `^[A-B][A-C]-[1-3][0-9]{3}$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for matching A, B or C and 1, 2 and 3 and use a quantifer `{3}` to match 3 digits 0-9

```
^[AB][ABC]-[123][0-9]{3}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y2d0Vk/1)

Or use a `$` at the end instead of `\b` if you want to match the whole string.

Comment: What if I wanted the starting letters to be ACE, AMP or BAT?

Comment: @RedUnited That depends on your requirements. If they should start with either of those strings, you could use an alternation `^(?:ACE|AMP|BAT)-[123][0-9]{3}\b` https://regex101.com/r/DBhkWX/1